# take screen shot of the entire view (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, save, photo

I just want to use a button to take a photo of the entire view controller. I think what I am trying to do is take a screen shot of the uiview and and save it in photo gallery. I want the button in the picture.

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var x: UIButton!
    var screenShot: UIImage?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
              }

    func saveScreen() {
        self.screenShot = screenshot()
        print("cool")
    }

    func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        let imageSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size as CGSize;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        for obj : AnyObject in UIApplication.shared.windows {
            if let window = obj as? UIWindow {
                if window.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIWindow.screen)) || window.screen == UIScreen.main {
                    // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
                    context!.saveGState();
                    // Center the context around the window's anchor point
                    context!.translateBy(x: window.center.x, y: window.center
                        .y);
                    // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
                    context!.concatenate(window.transform);
                    // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
                    context!.translateBy(x: -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x,
                                         y: -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);

                    // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
                    window.layer.render(in: context!)

                    // Restore the context
                    context!.restoreGState();
                }
            }
        }
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        return image!
    }
    @IBAction func saveUIVIEW(_ sender: Any) {
        self.screenShot = screenshot()
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. Original answer is here. [Screenshot on swift programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308685/screenshot-on-swift-programmatically)

> ```
> func screenshot() -> UIImage {
>     let imageSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size as CGSize;
>     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0)
>     let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
>     for obj : AnyObject in UIApplication.shared.windows {
>         if let window = obj as? UIWindow {
>             if window.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIWindow.screen)) || window.screen == UIScreen.main {
>                                 // so we must first apply the layer's geometry to the graphics context
>                                 context!.saveGState();
>                                 // Center the context around the window's anchor point
>                                 context!.translateBy(x: window.center.x, y: window.center
>                                     .y);
>                                 // Apply the window's transform about the anchor point
>                                 context!.concatenate(window.transform);
>                                 // Offset by the portion of the bounds left of and above the anchor point
>                 context!.translateBy(x: -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x,
>                                      y: -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);
>
>                                 // Render the layer hierarchy to the current context
>                                 window.layer.render(in: context!)
>
>                                 // Restore the context
>                                 context!.restoreGState();
>             }
>         }
>     }
>     let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
>     return image!
> }
> ```

Call:

```
func saveScreen() {
    let image = screenshot()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}

func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    if let error = error {
        // we got back an error!
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func saveUIVIEW(_ sender: Any) {
    saveScreen()
}
```

Comment: How do I call this function? I tried putting screenshot in the button and that did not work.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: I updated my question. My code compiles there are no run time errors however nothing is being saved to the photo gallery.

Comment: I updated my answer.