# Programmatic screenshot over current context viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift

The viewcontroller i am taking a screenshot from is set to "over current context" therefore showing an image and info in the view controller under it.

When i however take a screenshot programatically the screen turns black where it is supposed to be transparent therefore showing the viewcontroller under it.

how can this be solved?

```
let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
```

My code (Currently returning a black screen where id like it to be transparent showing Viewcontroller under)

Answer (score 0):

try to this code it's working good :

```swift
func screenShotMethod() {

        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
        // myView : change with your view
        myView.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)

        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img!, nil, nil, nil)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However it still remains black(not showing viewcontroller under)

Comment: The code posted here solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308685/screenshot-on-swift-programmatically